# Internet Explorer 7/8 cross-origin resource sharing JavaScript implementation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cors, same-origin-policy

Upon submitting a form from my website to third-party website, the HTTP post request will trigger downloading a file. This works fine with Firefox and Chrome. However, Internet Explorer 7/8 security setting prevent downloading the file by saying:

> file download blocked - To help protect your security Internet Explorer blocked this site from downloading files to your computer

I know this is a issue with CORS, which has been resolved in IE 9+, FF and Chrome. right now I need to support IE 8 bypassing the security setting. Is there any workaround I can do here? So basically what CORE does is to add a HTTP header request so that the server knows this is a request from different domain.

Comment: Does the 3rd party website redirect the user to a URL for the file or does it return the raw file contents immediately upon submitting the form? If you can get a URL for the file then you might be able to create some sort of server-side proxy, in case you can't solve this on the client side.

Comment: the 3rd party website return raw file content immediately upon submitting the form. I don't think I can get URL for the file.

Answer (score 0):

IF you search for the CORS solution for IE 7/8 you will have to use a  XDomainRequest. For IE 10+ browsers they have changed it to use XMLHTTPRequest. Have a look at following link to get a idea about CORS using XDR.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

http://amareswar.blogspot.com/2012/06/cors-issues-with-ie9-and-workarounds.html